# The RX of a BLE device needs to be on to wake it up via BLE?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

So some BLE devices have sleep mode which allows it to consume less power (significantly less, in the order of uA). In this state (I think) the radio (RX and TX) is off. So there's any way to wake it up from sleep mode via BLE?

OBS: Just for CONTEXT, the devices which I'm referring to are these CC2541,nRF8001,nRF51822...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So there's any way to wake him up from sleep mode via BLE?

Just start advertizing with a long period.

This way you need the high TX/RX current only for a very short time about once per second or even less often, which means your device is >99% in the low power sleeping state. Average current consumtion could go down to double digit µA range, but YMMV.